# Graphic application opening in the workspace it was first used instead of the current workspace

Tags: xmonad

I am using the image viewer geeqie under xmonad.

When I open geeqie for the first time, say in workspace 1, everything goes well. Now, if I quit geeqie on workspace 1, go to another workspace, and launch another geeqie instance, the window does not appear on my current workspace, but on the workspace 1.

What could cause this behavior?

Whatever cause the problem, I have tried to force geeqie to open in the current wokspace in the config file along the lines of

```
, className =? "geeqie" --> doShift (gets (W.currentTag . windowset))
```

but compilation fails with

```
• Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’
  Expected type: WorkspaceId
    Actual type: [WorkspaceId]
• In the first argument of ‘doShift’, namely
    ‘(gets (W.currentTag . windowset))
...
```

Maybe someone versed in Haskell could help me correct this workaround.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to configure your window manager to not remember the window size/position for applications. not sure if you can do this on app by app basis. either way, Geeqie shouldn't know or care a bit about where its being loaded, so it shouldn't be specific to any particular program.

Comment: It would indeed be surprising that such behavior would be specific to Geeqie, that's why I did not make it appear in the title. All I know is that so far Geeqie is the only application exhibiting this behavior.